# Ideas in Salesforce Communities

Tags: community, ideas

I need a ideas functionality on salesforce communities.I did something like below but the tabs and comments are not working.I tried with other options like isdtp=mn,istdp=lt as well but no luck.So thinking of building custom idea page like(http://mystarbucksidea.force.com/ideaHome
http://www.lincvolt.com/ideas/ideaList.apexp )..Is there any other options?

```
<apex:page showHeader="false" sidebar="false" standardStylesheets="false"  applyBodyTag="false"
   docType="html-5.0">
 <html lang="en">
<head>
 </head>
  <body>
       <apex:iframe id="iframe" src="/sam/ideas/ideaList.apexp?isdtp=nv" 
             scrolling="true" width="100%" height="1000px"/>

   </body>
</html> 
</apex:page>
```

Comment: What type of visual container are you using for your community? Visualforce/Sites, standard tabs, Site.com?

Comment: @greenstork visualforce/sites

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked into using the ideas Visualforce tags instead of using an iframe? I noticed when I tried to iframe pages in Visualforce a lot of the Chatter functionality got disabled (similar to what you were mentioning), so I went down that path. I believe you'll need to contact Salesforce support to get them to turn on these components for use.

http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_compref_ideas_listOutputLink.htm
http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_compref_ideas_detailOutputLink.htm
http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_compref_ideas_profileListOutputLink.htm